# How to aggregate a measure on a year-month level based on start and end date in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, count, recursive-query

I have a SQL query that pulls in three columns as below

```
employee_id  start_date  end_date       hours
123          09-01-2019  09-02-2019     8
123          09-28-2019  10-01-2019     32
```

I want to rewrite the query so instead of going granular, i just want to know the sum(hrs) an employee has on a year month level like below:

```
employee_id  Year_Month       hours
123          201909            32
123          201910            8
```

The employee has 4 days in September so 4*8=32 and one day in october so 8 hours for the month of October. My issue is when there are start and end dates that cross between adjacent months. I'm not sure how to write a query to get my desired output and I'd really appreciate any help on this

Comment: Could you please provide the sample of original data.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use a recursive query to generate series of days in each month, then aggregate by month and count:

```
with
    data as (< your existing query here >), 
    cte (employee_id, dt, max_dt) as (
        select employee_id, start_date, end_date from data
        union all
        select employee_id, dt + 1, max_dt from cte where dt + 1 < max_dt
    )

select employee_id, to_char(dt, 'yyyymm')  year_months, count(*) * 8 hours
from mytable
group by employee_id, to_char(dt, 'yyyymm')
```

This assumes 8 hours per day, as explained in your question.

Comment: In the example I've given 8 hours but it can vary.  so ideally it would be the number of days between the two dates multiplied by the hours column. In that case would this work if i replace count(*) * 8 by count (*) * hours?

Comment: @PrashanthChitrambalam: probably, you mean `sum(hours)` then. But in that case you need the `cte` to return column `hours` too.